# iText BarcodeDataMatrix throws ArrayIndexOutofBounds Exception for some input

Tags: java, itext

It is able to generate the barcode in some cases, while it fails for others throwing a ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception. 
Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
String barcode="10e5ae5147d20db19651f90247621699";
BarcodeDatamatrix datamatrix = new BarcodeDatamatrix();
datamatrix.generate(barcode);
datamatrix.setHeight(22);
img = datamatrix.createImage();
img.setAbsolutePosition(175, 750);
```

When the input string used to create the barcode hex string has less number of characters it is working. When I increase the number of characters in the input string it fails.It is failing for the hex string given here.
Here is the stack trace:

```
Barcode string is :10e5ae5147d20db19651f90247621699
Print barcode
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.codec.CCITTG4Encoder.pixel([BII)I(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.codec.CCITTG4Encoder.Fax3Encode2DRow()V(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.codec.CCITTG4Encoder.fax4Encode([BII)V(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.codec.CCITTG4Encoder.compress([BII)[B(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.BarcodeDatamatrix.createImage()Lcom.lowagie.text.Image;(Unknown Source)
    at com.sample.common.util.ItextUtils.barcode(ItextUtils.java:294)
```

Comment: Add complete stacktrace.

Comment: Which cases, and which others?

Answer (score 0):

If you can not render a data matrix code, you should try this method:

```
System.out.println(datamatrix.generate("10e5ae5147d20db19651f90247621699"));
```

This method returns one of the following values:

```
/**
 * No error.
 */
public static final int DM_NO_ERROR = 0;
/**
 * The text is too big for the symbology capabilities.
 */
public static final int DM_ERROR_TEXT_TOO_BIG = 1;
/**
 * The dimensions given for the symbol are illegal.
 */
public static final int DM_ERROR_INVALID_SQUARE = 3;
/**
 * An error while parsing an extension.
 */
public static final int DM_ERROR_EXTENSION = 5;
```

In your case `"10e5ae5147d20db19651f90247621699"` returns 3 (`DM_ERROR_INVALID_SQUARE`) which means that the dimensions you defined for the symbol are illegal.

Indeed: if you would remove the line `datamatrix.setHeight(22);` (in which case iText defines the dimensions) or if you would use an appropriate height for the data (e.g. replace `22` with `20`), then you don't get an exception.

I also see my name (I am Lowagie) in your code. My I inform you that you are using a version of iText that is at lease 5 and a half years old and that you can no longer use that version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696851/can-itext-2-1-7-or-earlier-can-be-used-commercially